# Configuração do Django-allauth

Tags: python, django, email, login

Galera, estou tentando implementar o **django-allauth** em um projeto pessoal porém não estou conseguindo, na versão 0.20.0 é fácil mas queria tentar na mais recente que é a 0.25.2, não me apresenta nenhum erro, porém quando acesso a url http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/ nada acontece, segue o código:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'plantonista',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.core.context_processors.debug',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.core.context_processors.media',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
                'django.core.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
                #'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
                #'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
                'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Django-Allauth
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = LOGIN_URL
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = None

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 3
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = "My subject: "
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "http"

ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = False
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = None
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD = "email"

ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 5
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST = []
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_INPUT_RENDER_VALUE = False
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 6
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você esqueceu de incluir o allauth nas URLs do projeto:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```